# Obtener cantidad de dias de semana del mes en PHP (sin los fines de semana)

Tags: php, date

¿Cómo puedo obtener la cantidad de días del mes sin sábados ni domingos en general para cualquier mes?

Ejemplo:

- Diciembre = 31 días
- Sábados y Domingos del mes = 9 días

[image: calendario de diciembre 2016]

> 31 - 9 = 22 días.

Con un "echo" para mostrarlo.

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el código que has intentado?

Comment: Yo tengo una solución, espero a que la reabran..